# Android Lollipop contacts retrieving null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-5.0-lollipop, android-contacts

I get null pointer exception at cursor moveToFirst() when retrieving contacts phone number on Lollipop devices but in other OS version it working fine.

Exception occur at `pCur.moveToFirst(); under the getContact() method`

please see my code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public static Context mContext;
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> name = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> contactDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, Bitmap> image = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    private Cursor pCur, contactsCursor;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String[] PROJECTION = { Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
                Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY };

        String SELECTION = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + "<>''" + " AND "
                + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1" + " AND "
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        String SORT_ORDER = Contacts.SORT_KEY_ALTERNATIVE;
        contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, SORT_ORDER);
        StoreCursor.qcursor = contactsCursor;
        Log.e("cur", "cur" + StoreCursor.qcursor.getCount());
        getContact();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void getContact() {
        Log.e("result cursor", "" + contactsCursor.getCount());
        String displayName;
        String contactId;
        contactsCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            displayName = contactsCursor.getString(2);
            contactId = contactsCursor.getString(0);
            // Log.e("disName & id", displayName + "  "+contactId);
            pCur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { contactId }, null);
            String cPN = "";

                pCur.moveToFirst(); // NullPointerException occur here.
                do {
                    int phoneType = pCur
                            .getInt(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    String phoneNumber = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    switch (phoneType) {
                    case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        cPN = cPN + "(mobile number)" + phoneNumber + "\n";
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        cPN = cPN + "(home number)" + phoneNumber + "\n";
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        cPN = cPN + "(work number)" + phoneNumber + "\n";
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                        cPN = cPN + "(other number)" + phoneNumber + "\n";
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                } while (pCur.moveToNext());
                name.put(contactId, displayName);
                Log.e("displayName", displayName);
                StoreCursor.name = name;
                contactDetails.put(contactId, cPN);
                StoreCursor.contactDetails = contactDetails;
                String photo = contactsCursor.getString(3) + "~";
                // Log.e("photo url", photo);
                if (photo.length() > 6) {
                    openPhoto(Long.valueOf(contactId), displayName);
                }

        } while (contactsCursor.moveToNext());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one:

If `pCur.moveToFirst();` throws a NullPointerException, this means that `pCur` is `null`. Since `pCur` is only set in one place,

```
pCur = getContentResolver().query(...);
```

this means that your call to `ContentResolver.query` returns `null`.

Now the *real* question is: Why does `ContentResolver.query` return `null`? That's a good question, and I suggest that you ask it as a new question here on SO. Be sure to include all relevant information, i.e.:

- which URL are you trying to resolve,
- which parameters do you use and where to you get them from,
- etc.

Ideally, you should add a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your new question (note that your current code snippet is neither minimal nor complete).

Comment: Seems as if the selection and sort order queries are not syntatically correct, which will produce incompatible SQL.